# Error setting Dependency Property value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a "RoomType" class, and I'm creating a user control that can take the RoomType as property and show the name. I'm trying to bind a user control with the property as shown below:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Type", typeof(RoomType), typeof(RoomTypeBox));

    public RoomType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return (RoomType)GetValue(TypeProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(TypeProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I set the value (a RoomType object) to the property, it throws "StackOverFlow Exception", I allready debugged step by step and no infinite loops are present.

Here is the XAML for the UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="NH_Motel.Components.RoomTypeBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="310.667" Height="28">
<Grid Name="Base" Height="28">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="180*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="..." HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="btnSelect" Width="47" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment" Height="28" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle3}" Click="btnSelect_Click" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txbText" Height="28" Margin="0,0,51,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Template="{DynamicResource TextBoxControlTemplate1}" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Text="{Binding Type.Text}"/>
</Grid>
```

The TextBox Template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded1">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContentHost">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF6A7FCE"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnGotFocus1"/>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF494949" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="#FFC1C5D4" FontFamily="Arial" BorderThickness="0"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FocusManager.GotFocus">
            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OnLoaded1_BeginStoryboard"/>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnLoaded1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnLoaded1}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Post your XAML. All applicable Styles and Templates for this control.

Comment: Seems fine to me.. how do you set your value? `Type = new RoomType();`?

Comment: Which class is declaring this property?

Comment: I insist: the error `might` be in XAML. I had these `StackOverflowException`s before caused by recursive triggers or other XAML stuff. Post your XAML.

Comment: Acturus, yes I set the value like that, "Type = new RoomType();"

Comment: Jon Skeet, the class declaring the property is "RoomTypeBox", the user control created for contain a RoomType and represent its name in a TextField

Comment: Are you sure it's the `DependencyProperty` causing the exception? I've occasionally triggered that exception when I have a `ControlTemplate` contain the control itself somewhere in it, which causes the `ControlTemplate` to render repeatedly until it eventually throws a StackOverflow exception. Can you try commenting out everything in your UserControl except something basic with no styles, like a TextBox, and see if it works? Also from what you've posted, your DP shouldn't even work at all since your `TextBox.Text` binding refers to the `DataContext`, and not the `UserControl`.